# How to redirect a user to his own data after editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profile, show

I got the following code:

```
 def edit
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
  end   

def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])  

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, 
         notice: 'Profile succesfully modified`.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



def show
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

**routes**

```
resources :users

get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
get "profile" => "users#show", :as => "profile"
get "edit_profile" => "users#edit", :as => "edit_profile"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect the user to his profile after updating his informations.

But I get the following when I submit the changes

```
    Template is missing

    Missing template users/update, application/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
 :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: *   "/Users/blakee/Desktop/ruby/scorergui/app/views"
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have defined a `show` action in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect to that user, you are redirecting to the show method.

You need the following views in app/views/users:

1. show.html.erb
2. edit.html.erb

As long as you have those, you should be good. I'm guessing you don't have show.

Comment: I already have those templates.I think that It's not a template problem